# Using PHP+MySQL a web-app, where registered, logged user can add some text, which is commentable by other logged, registered users

Tags: php, sql, web-applications

I want to do using PHP+MySQL a web-app, where registered, logged user can add question or add a comment to the question (unlogged, unregistered user can only read questions and its answers).

The main problem is, how to express in PHP+MySQL the comment to the right straight question. (not to all questions in one, but directly to the right one)

Thank you for all posibilities in way of solving this problem.

Comment: not got your question but i think this is what you may ...                           You can create a 'comment' table, with an id as primary key, then you add a text field to capture the text inserted by the user and you need another field to link the comment table to the some table (foreign key). Plus you need a field to store the user that has entered a comment, this field can be the user's email. Then you capture via GET or POST the user's email and comment and you insert everything in the DB:

Comment: use session to store the logged in users username and in the mysql table also store the username of the person who posted the question and while rendering the page ensure that you show edit buttons for only those questions where question writers username == the logged in username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a simple database design question.

You are describing 3 tables: users, questions, comments.
Comments table has a foreign key of QuestionID, the question in which the comment was posted. It also has a foreign key of PosterID, which is the ID of the user who posted the comment.
To view the comments related to a specific question, fetch them by their QuestionID.

Here's a sample SQL query in PHP to fetch comments for a specific question:

```
$questionId = 5;
$query = "SELECT *
FROM comments
WHERE question_id={$questionId}";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

I also suggest learning about SQL injection and preferably using [PDO prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to construct your queries (The sample I've given uses simple mysqli).

Comment: "User writes a question, and another user can comment it, the question, and comment could be done by logged, registered users."  Well, yes it exactly is maybe the right solution (a database logic i suppose absolutely right), but, how could i do "fetching" itself ? How could i exactly insure that the comment will be related to the specific question ?

Comment: I will try and answer a result, thank you very much :).